# CollapsingToolBarLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

For the past few months I have been using Collapsing Toolbar Layout with no problem. However today, this error pops up whenever I open the xml file. The exact error reads:

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Here is the stack trace:

```
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:656)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:111)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(TintTypedArray.java:55)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:202)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:199)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**CollapsingToolBarLayout.xml**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/custom_view1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/black"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:clickable="true"
          >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_button"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"


          />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Upon running the app in the emulator, the toolbar works just fine, but I'm still confused why this is happening in android studio. I've cleared caches, rebuilt, rechecked Support Library Versions, and everything else I could think of. What am I missing?

Comment: Try not setting a color Reference for a Textappearance at: app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/black"

Comment: Whoa, that worked! But why? And what's the workaround for setting the titleColor?

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/black
```

Instead of this, to change title colors, use one of methods described here:

[Correct way to change Collapseble Toolbar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302121/correct-way-to-change-collapseble-toolbar-title)

Also update your Android Support Libraries to `24.2.1` version.