# android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout could not be instantiated

Tags: android, xml

I am a newbie here;

I want to make an Android app for my school project, and I have been experimenting with `RecyclerView` and `CardView`. I was following this tutorial here at:

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

I ran into some problems when I tried to do step 9: copy out the code into `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml`.

Under the XML preview for `activity_main.xml` in Android Studio, it would say:

Image of rendering problem under Preview

[image]

and the stack error is:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:656)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:71)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1436)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:587)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(TintTypedArray.java:59)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setExpandedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:231)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:196)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor350.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This happened even when I included `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'` under my `build.gradle`.

I have already researched on this link [CollapsingToolBarLayout could not be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664647/collapsingtoolbarlayout-could-not-be-instantiated) and this case did not apply for me, as the tutorial does not include any `collapsedTitleTextAppearance` XML attribute for the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I tried downloading the src code from androidhive but it was kind of messed up and I couldn't find what went wrong.

Could someone tell me what went wrong with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and how do i fix it? Thanks!

Meeps

**EDIT: Added content for `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml`**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/viewBg"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.alcheong.cardviewexample.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just to say, I didn't include the content of any of my Java or XML files because there were just too many and they were identical to the ones on the tutorial anyway.

Comment: Hmm so now become a place where we fix tutorial issues **Why dont you post a comment at that site comments thread first?** , anyway can you post your xml

Comment: *they were identical to the ones on the tutorial anyway* Do you expect us to go there and find the right one for you friend?

Comment: oh :P ok sorry i post

Comment: ok i posted already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, kind of a bug with android studio.

If it's problematic to view the preview as a workaround for this issue you can replace your `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` with a `FrameLayout` when you want to edit it in the visual design editor(Then is error will disappear), make your changes to the layout and then *change it back* to a `CoordinatorLayout` when you are finished.

At the run-time you wont have a problem.

Find more details here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175595